# How can i increase the default width of the advanced search form in the latest jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

in jqgrid 4.0, i am trying to see if you can change the width of the advanced search screen
Right now a horizontal scroll bar comes up). Is there anyway to make the width of the form bigger as it seems to not be adjustable.

Here is a pic:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you just increase the initial searching dialog inside of `beforeShowSearch`:

```
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false},{},{},{},
                  { multipleSearch:true,
                    beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
                        $('#searchmodfbox_'+grid[0].id).width(560);
                  }
            );
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAdvSearching.htm).

Comment: this seems to no longer work in jqGrid 4.40. looks like you have to add a Return true' after the .width() call

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and it worked.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridPager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,refresh: false},{},{},{},
              { 
                beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
                    $('#searchmodfbox_grid').width(760);
                    return true;
              }
              }
        );
```

In this search dialog's div id is { "searchmodfbox_" + yourGridId } . In my case my grid id is grid then search dialog's Id is "`searchmodfbox_grid`". And this is for jqgrid 4.4