# JQGRID search resize

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to increase the jqgrid searchbox width dynamically based on the column width.

I have tried to do this inside `beforeshowsearch` event. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `beforeShowSearch` (!!! not `beforeshowsearch`) to make changes in the searching dialog. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080245/315935) for the code example (you can use `this.id` instead of `grid[0].id` if you use recent version of jqGrid). I recommend you to use `recreateFilter: true` searching option additionally.

By the way `navGrid` which add "Search" button to the navigator bar uses `width` property of `prmSearch` parameter on every call of `searchGrid` method which creates the grid. So if you would hold `prmSearch` and just change `width` the next search dialog will uses new width value:

```js
var pSearch = {
        recreateFilter: true,
        multipleSearch:true,
        width: 500
    };

$("#list").jqGrid({...}); // create the grid

$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {}, {}, {}, {}, pSearch);
// if the user opens searching dialog now the width 500 will be used

...
pSearch.width = 800;
// if the user opens searching dialog now the new width 800 will be used
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. But the problem is I havent used return True inside beforeShowSearch and hence it wasnt working

Comment: @user1986736: You are welcome! If you have any (even not working) solution you should post the corresponding code and write which version of jqGrid you use. It's difficult to guess what problem you have.